# What is the proper syntax for Mutex

Tags: ruby, multithreading, mutex

I can not figure out what is wrong with the following but I keep getting syntax errors for the closing "}" brace. I was under the assumption that this was the proper syntax for Mutex based on http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Mutex.html

```
  semaphore = Mutex.new 

  semaphore.synchronize {
    r_failure.push( username )
    thread_count--
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with `Mutex`. The problem is:

```
thread_count--
```

You cannot use `-` in a variable name or a method (unless doing it in a special, unusual way).